# Tamaño de imágenes de fondo para una aplicación iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

Necesito hacer fondos para una aplicación en Swift, tengo las medidas de los distintos tamaños para cada iPhone:

```
Device          Points    Pixels     Scale  Physical Pixels   Physical PPI  Size
iPhone 6  plus  736x414   2208x1242  3x     1920x1080         401           5.5"
iPhone 6        667x375   1334x750   2x     1334x750          326           4.7"
iPhone 5        568x320   1136x640   2x     1136x640          326           4.0"
iPhone 4        480x320   960x640    2x     960x640           326           3.5"
iPhone 3GS      480x320   480x320    1x     480x320           163           3.5"
```

Tengo dos dudas:

1. ¿El tamaño de mis imágenes debe ser el de la columna `Physical Pixels`?
2. ¿Cuál es el tamaño para un fondo para el iPad e iPad Mini?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La resolución de las imágenes debe ser la resolución que dice en la columna `Pixels`. Para todos los efectos, ese es el tamaño de pantalla, aunque los pixeles reales sean otros.

Este documento (en inglés) tiene una muy buena explicación: [iPhone 6 Screens Demystified](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified).

Para el iPad, los tamaños en pixeles son 768x1024 y 1536x2048 (no retina y retina respectivamente). No importa que sea iPad o iPad Mini, en pixeles son iguales.

Answer (score 0):

Te respondo:

1. No, es la columna `Pixels`
2. 1024x768 a `@1x` para todos los iPad excepto para el iPad Pro